# When using more than 16 math alphabets, \mathtt uses italic font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, luatex

I know that in TeX, you can only use 16 math alphabets but XeTeX extends this so I was curious to enlarge the number of my math alphabets and I had to redefine some internals of LaTeX. Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}         {U}  {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyB}         {U}  {MnSymbolB}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}         {U}  {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD}         {U}  {MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyE}         {U}  {MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\def\select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
  \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \init@restore@version
     \xdef#1{\noexpand\use@mathgroup\noexpand#2%
             {\number\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}}%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used in
                   version \math@version}%
        \@eha
   \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}
\def\document@select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
   \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\extract@alph@from@version
         \csname mv@\math@version\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\number\csname
                       c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}%
          #1%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used
                   in version \math@version}%
        \@eha
  \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}
\makeatother


\DeclareSymbolFont{testa}   {U}{cmr10} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testb}{U}{cmr10}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testc}{U}{cmr10}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testd}{U}{cmr10}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}


\begin{document}
\[ \mathtt{Test}\]    
\end{document}
```

But this makes the word `test` to appear in italic. You can delete any of the `\DeclareSymbolFont` and then `\mathtt` worked as expected. This shows that this only happens when the number of math alphabets exceeds 16. Why does this happen and how should one fix this?

**Update1:** I tried the same thing with LuaTeX and I got expected result so it seems that something is wrong with XeTeX.

**Update2:** Another minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\def\select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
  \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \init@restore@version
     \xdef#1{\noexpand\use@mathgroup\noexpand#2%
             {\number\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}}%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used in
                   version \math@version}%
        \@eha
   \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}
\def\document@select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
   \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\extract@alph@from@version
         \csname mv@\math@version\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\number\csname
                       c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}%
          #1%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used
                   in version \math@version}%
        \@eha
  \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}

\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{testa}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testb}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testc}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{testd}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathtt{Test} \mathcal{L}\]
\end{document}
```

No problem with LuaLaTeX, but with XeLaTeX, this time, `\mathtt` is fine but you get italic with `\mathcal`.

Comment: Adding `\showthe\textfont16` after the formula produces a `Bad number (16)` error with XeLaTeX and `\OMS/MnSymbolS/m/n/10` with LuaLaTeX, so this seems like a bug in XeTeX.

Answer (score 12):

XeTeX’s `\fam` primitive does not seem to have been extended to accept higher values, and since the legacy mathcode format does allow higher families as well (e.g. with `\mathchar` and `\mathcode`), the only way to access higher math families for now is through extended math primitives. A simpler test:

```
\tracingonline=1
\font\cmscten=cmcsc10 at 10pt
\font\dunhten=cmdunh10 at 10pt
\textfont15=\cmscten
\textfont16=\dunhten
$$
\fam15 a
\fam16 A
\XeTeXmathchar"0 16 `A
\showlists
$$
\bye
```

Even if `\fam` was extended, it is still unreliable to use higher math families with legacy math setup because of the limitations of other math primitives (like `\mathchar` and `\mathcode`) which can not be extended in a backward compatible way, and thus existing packages will work unexpectedly when used with higher math families. Also, extended math primitives are not direct substitute for some legacy ones, for example `\XeTeXdelcode` can’t be used as a substitute for `\delcode` because it requires an OpenType math font and will not work as expected with legacy math fonts.

So, for all practical purposes, the check in LaTeX kernel should be kept, unless one is moving to a Unicode/OpenType–only math setup where higher math families can be used reliably (but then one is unlikely to ever need more than 16 `\fam`’s because Unicode/OpenType requires much less `\fam`’s than the legacy setup).

***Update:** In XeTeX [git repository](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=git&group_id=194926),`\fam` now handles numbers < 256 properly, and the `\showthe\textfont` issue (pointed by Enrico) is fixed is well, and both fixes are now included in TeX Live 2012.*

Comment: Seems something to be solved: `\textfont` accepts 16 as argument, but then `\the\textfont16` raises an error.

Comment: I saw your above comment, I’m working on it already.

Comment: I had no doubt! Thanks! Unfortunately TeX Live 2012 seems to be already frozen. :(

Comment: It is past being frozen, more like released-but-yet-to-be-announced.

Comment: @egreg: I think I fixed it, but it is too late for TL2012.

Comment: I remember something about that written some time ago (more than one year, I believe) by Andrew Moschou, relating to his `mathspec` package. Pity he didn't file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the fix but I do not agree with your comments. Regardless of one using unicode math (which is irrelevant here), one may use several math font packages in LaTeX which exceeds the number of math alphabets so at least XeTeX should behave exactly the same as LuaTeX.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: Please read my comments again, you can't use higher math families with any symbol that is not defined as `\mathalpha`. For testing, try adding 3 more `\DeclareSymbolFont` to your last test file, and load `amsfonts` and `MnSymbol` **after** them, now see what happens when using `*-><`.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by `*-><` but when I add 3 more \DeclareSymbolFont, I get `No room for a new \mathgroup error`. I am not sure if this is what you meant?

Comment: OK, try this file http://www.khaledhosny.org/files/tmp/test1.tex

Comment: It turned out that TL2012 was going to be built anyway for other reasons, so the two fixes were applied.

Comment: @KhaledHosny That's great news! I updated my pretest release and the bugs seem to have been really fixed. Good job!