# Which version of LaTeX permits more than 16 alphabets?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, errors, pdftex, miktex

Sometimes I receive a message:

> ! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

I know that there is a limit of 16 alphabets at most allowed to one article. However this message specified **version normal**, so are there any other version of LaTeX permitting more than 16 alphabets?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error

Comment: The `normal` there refered to `\mathversion{normal}` as opposed to `\mathversion{bold}` not the latex engine.  As @egreg says you can use xe/lua latex but usually you can arrange not to use so many math alphabets in standard latex as well. In particular any alphabets such as \mathrm \mathit etc could usually instead be accessed as text fonts  \textrm{} etc and avoid using up one of the math font slots.

Comment: Why do you need more than 16 math alphabets?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Well, says frankly I'm writing an article in logic. Thus need abundant fonts to avoid ambiguity. Take an example, we usually use `\mathfrak{A}` to denote a single structure, whereas use `\mathsf{A}` to denote a structure class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use more that 16 math groups (math alphabets, in particular) with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; here's an example. One must also change the allocation mechanism, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\new@mathgroup{\alloc@8\mathgroup\mathchardef\@cclvi}
\def\document@select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
   \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\extract@alph@from@version
         \csname mv@\math@version\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\number\csname
                       c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}%
          #1%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used
                   in version \math@version}%
        \@eha
  \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}
\def\select@group#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup\else\relax\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
 {%
 \ifmmode
  \ifnum\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname<\@cclvi
     \begingroup
       \escapechar\m@ne
       \getanddefine@fonts{\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}#3%
       \globaldefs\@ne  \math@fonts
     \endgroup
     \init@restore@version
     \xdef#1{\noexpand\use@mathgroup\noexpand#2%
             {\number\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname}}%
     \global\advance\csname c@mv@\math@version\endcsname\@ne
   \else
     \let#1\relax
     \@latex@error{Too many math alphabets used in
                   version \math@version}%
        \@eha
   \fi
 \else \expandafter\non@alpherr\fi
 #1{#4}%
 }%
}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mA}{OT1}{pcr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mB}{OT1}{pcr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mC}{OT1}{pcr}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mD}{OT1}{pcr}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mE}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mF}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mG}{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mH}{OT1}{ptm}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mI}{OT1}{pag}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mJ}{OT1}{pag}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mK}{OT1}{pag}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mL}{OT1}{pag}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mM}{OT1}{pbk}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mN}{OT1}{pbk}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mO}{OT1}{pbk}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mP}{OT1}{pbk}{b}{it}

\begin{document}
$
\mathbf{X}
\mathit{X}
\mathsf{X}
\mathtt{X}
\mA{X}
\mB{X}
\mC{X}
\mD{X}
\mE{X}
\mF{X}
\mG{X}
\mH{X}
\mI{X}
\mJ{X}
\mK{X}
\mL{X}
\mM{X}
\mN{X}
\mO{X}
\mP{X}
$
\end{document}
```

One could do without copying all that stuff with a simpler patch; the following code should replace all that in the previous one is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\new@mathgroup{\alloc@8\mathgroup\mathchardef\@cclvi}
\patchcmd{\document@select@group}{\sixt@@n}{\@cclvi}{}{}
\patchcmd{\select@group}{\sixt@@n}{\@cclvi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Compiling the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex` will show the following horror; of course you'll have better use cases.

[image]

## Important remark

As Khaled Hosny quite rightly observes, there is a very important limitation: this can work *only* for math alphabets; it's impossible to define `\mathchar` values that use the extended set (the XeTeX or LuaTeX extensions should be used). Thus one has to be careful when using math symbol fonts which must be loaded in memory *before* the math alphabets. So, if , say, `stmaryrd` is loaded, it's best to ensure that a formula using it is typeset before using the new math alphabets; a `\sbox0{$\Ydown$}` in the preamble should be sufficient, because so a math group will be permanently allocated for `stmaryrd`.

Comment: It seems a bit "surreal" to declare  new alphabets for LuaTeX and XeLaTeX with `OT1` encoding:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides That's only an example; probably `\DeclareSymbolFont` would make for a more interesting one. I was just too lazy for hunting through font catalogs.

Comment: It's wonderful!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides This code might make easier the life for the maintainer of the LaTeX symbol list.

Comment: @egreg ... Was thinking about it too! For most of the packages over the math alphabet limit they went the text route though.

Comment: @egreg Well, I have tested your codes and eventually found it works via LuaLaTex but doesn't work via XeLaTeX. If use XeLaTeX it seems only the first 12 fonts reveal correctly.

Comment: @Popopo You probably have an outdated version of XeTeX; the version in TeX Live 2012 (and possibly MiKTeX 2.9, but I'm not sure) has corrected a bug regarding math groups. You should have XeTeX version 0.9998 for this to work.

Comment: @egreg My version of XeTeX is 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9).

Comment: @Popopo Sorry; I'm not a MiKTeX user. It's possible that the bug fix found its way in TeX Live and not in MiKTeX, while the version number didn't change. It was a last minute fix just before TeX Live 2012 was frozen for release. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61027/4427

Comment: @egreg Can we fix it manually?

Comment: @Popopo No. It requires recompiling the binary from the sources; until C. Schenk doesn't do it, you're stuck.

Comment: @egreg What a pity...

Comment: @egreg I have an idea: to install TeX live 2012, then graft XeTeX files to MiKTeX. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Popopo I don't think it can work.

Comment: @egreg You are right, they're a bit different.

Comment: XeTeX and LuaTeX can use more than 16 math families, but legacy math primitives (`\mathchar`, `\delcode`, etc) can not use higher families and the output for any thing but class 7 symbols using higher math family will be wrong.

Comment: @KhaledHosny The question was about using math alphabets; so exactly for class 7 symbols. There's nothing in the answer that suggests one can use higher families for other than letters, but I'll add it for clarity.

Comment: @egreg: That is better now. I’ve failing for this for long time, that I’m trying to make sure others don’t :)

Comment: @KhaledHosny One *might* try to extend the `\DeclareMathSymbol` command for using `\XeTeXmathchar` instead of `\mathchar`. Hard work, maybe, and probably quite useless if done only for compiling more easily the Comprehensive List of Symbols. :)

Comment: I'd stick something like `\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex} \begingroup \newif\ifModern\Modernfalse \ifxetex\Moderntrue\fi \ifluatex\Moderntrue\fi \ifModern \def\action{\endgroup} \else \def\action{\endgroup<some kind of error message}\fi \action` in there such that if one tried to compile with `latex` or `pdflatex` it would output an error message.

Comment: @egreg: You still have `\delcode` and `\delimiter` which has no equivalent since `\Udelcode` and `\Udelimeter` work differently (there is no large family).

Comment: Note that in the upcoming (2015) LaTeX2e release `\new@mathgroup` will be updated to allow 256 slots with XeTeX/LuaTeX.